# Trying to extract a substring from a buffered reader that reads between certain tags

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I'm extracting 5 webpages using bufferedreader, each separated by a space, I want to use a substring to extract each pages url, html, source, and date. But I need guidance on how to use the substring properly to achieve this, cheers.

```
public static List<WebPage> readRawTextFile(Context ctx, int resId) {   

    InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(
            R.raw.pages);

    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
    String line;
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {


            if (line.length() == 0) {       
                // ignore for now 
                                //Will be used when blank line is encountered
            }

            if (line.length() != 0)  {
         //here I want the substring to pull out the correctStrings
                int sURL = line.indexOf("<!--");
                    int eURL = line.indexOf("-->");
                line.substring(sURL,eURL);
                **//Problem is here**
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: How I want the text to be extracted is like this for the address I want to remove the tags <!--Address:http://www.google.co.uk.html--> So that I am left with this so i can store it: http://www.google.co.uk.html

Comment: Why do you want to go through substring operation? Just use String.replace() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In catch block don't `return null`, use `printStackTrace();`. It will help you to find if something went wrong.

```
        String str1 = "<!--Address:google.co.uk.html-->";
        // Approach 1
        int st = str1.indexOf("<!--"); // gives index which starts from <
        int en = str1.indexOf("-->");  // gives index which starts from -
        str1 = str1.substring(st + 4, en);
        System.out.println(str1);

        // Approach 2
        String str2 = "<!--Address:google.co.uk.html-->";
        str2 = str2.replaceAll("[<>!-]", "");
        System.out.println( str2);
```

**Note $100:** be aware that using regex in replaceAll it will replace everything in string containing regex params.

Comment: Thanks, I need to be able to extract the addresses from the bufferedreader though. So it would go through and find each address in the text file take the tags off and return the addresses

Comment: @rob12243 I don't understand. Anyway you can use any of the logics to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

I think what u want is like this ,

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
    String text = "<!--Address:google.co.uk.html-->";
    String converted1 = text.replaceAll("\\<!--", "");
    String converted2 = converted1.replaceAll("\\-->", "");
    System.out.println(converted2);
   }
```

}

result show : Address:google.co.uk.html

Comment: Thanks i'll see if i can adapt it so I can save the 5 urls.

Comment: As you are using `ReplaceAll()`. Then why these two conversion. You can achieve same by using `regex`. +1 Anyway.